# Group two column list to sorted array

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

In my current project I am maintaining long list of one to many correspondences in Excel.

Basically, I am trying now to sort the items in the first and collect the second item by additional columns as being shown in the table below. The second table below is somehow a compressed form of the the table above.

How can this be achieved with a simple Excel formula not involving some VBA scripting? My lists are much longer than the ones in the example, e.g. containing thousands of lines. So the solution must be also somehow efficient.

The items in the first column A,B,C don't need to be sorted, but might be nice if possible.

Can anybody help me out here, as I am really not an Excel pro.

Just found out that the first column can be retrieved with `=UNIQUE(A1:A8)`
whereas for the second column a somewhat intelligent combination of `IF` and `INDEX` might work.

[image: Example of what I am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

After some trying around I found the following solution, that at least worked for the small example.

`=TRANSPOSE(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER($A$1:$B$8,$A$1:$A$8=H13),2))`